# C++ - What is the difference between inlines defined in CPP and H

Tags: c++, inline-functions

This is less of an "I'm having this issue" question, and more of an "I really want to understand how the language works better" question.

I've recently started encountering definitions of inline functionality in .cpp files for a given class. I'd like to understand what the difference between the definition points for inline functionality actually is. In doing an object level analysis of inlines defined in the CPP, it seems like a much higher percentage of the inlines declared in the C++ (as opposed to being defined in the .h) are optimized to mapped functions instead of being legitimately inlined - is this the major difference, or is there some other purpose behind this entirely which I'm not seeing.

Comment: Could you please present some code examples? It really isn't clear what you are saying.

Comment: Specifically, I was looking for the difference between 

inline Class::foo(void){ stuff } being placed in the .h for a given class versus it being placed in the .cpp for a given class.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. `inline` is a hint to the compiler, but isn't particularly important these days, since compilers are pretty good at figuring out whether to expand functions inline without your help (see `register` keyword).

`inline` also tells the compiler that multiple definitions in different translation units are okay (provided they're the same), which is needed when you put an inline function in a header file.

When an inline function is defined in a .cpp file its definition is only visible in that file, so calling it from some other source file won't work.

Answer (score 2):

`inline` functions don't make sense without *one and only one single definition per translation unit*, so it makes sense to place it in a header file, where the  definition may be reused. When an `inline` function is only used in one source file, it makes sense  to define it locally. It's all a matter of context.

Comment: That's not quite true.  It depends on your compiler.  For example, if you use Visual C++, you can turn on "whole program optimization."  In this case, the linker can inline functions regardless of whether they're defined in the same translation unit.

Comment: According to the C++03 standard, §7.1.2.4
"**An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is used and shall have exactly the
same definition in every case (§3.2).**" I am not particularly concerned with specific compilers' extensions :-p

Comment: May I humbly suggest that you should be?  Whole program optimization is an _awesome_ feature.

Comment: @PeterRuderman haha, very well then... I'm not even a C++ programmer, but next time I'm forced to write C++ code I'll try it out :-)

Comment: @PeterRuderman, I think he's right - even if you're using whole program optimization it would inline the function regardless of whether you used the `inline` keyword.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be creating some confusion between the "inline" keyword and the verb _to inline_.  You are correct: the compiler does not need the "inline" keyword in order to _inline_ a function.  (And actually, I think most modern compilers ignore the "inline" keyword completely and make up their own minds about what to _inline_.)

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the difference is a result of your compiler not doing "link-time"/"whole-program" optimization. This is when the compiler performs optimizations while looking at the whole program instead of just a single translation unit. It's often not turned on by default even in compilers that support it because it typically involves very high memory usage.

When only optimizing on the translation-unit level, it's not possible to inline functions that are defined in other source files because the definition is not available.

Answer (score 1):

An inline function is easier for the compiler to inline if it is defined before the call rather than after. Since header files are typically included at the top of the source, this condition is more easily met.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is *no* difference.

Although I don't know much about optimizations with them, think of it...
 Preprocessor will first expand the .h file where it finds `#include` in .cpp file. And *then* it will be presented to the compiler. So technically there is no difference at all.

But, there is a rule:

> An `inline` function must be defined in every compilation unit in which it is called. (Of course, ODR must be followed).

This is because, every compilation unit is handled by a separate instance of the compiler program.

Hence, usually, inline function are defined in the header file which is included in every .cpp file in which there is a call to that function.